# Add list Context Menu Item with ItemId in sharepoint 2007

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I am adding menu item in defult context menu in sharepoint 2007. 
I put this code in source editor web pat. This code is not working...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Custom_AddListMenuItems(m, ctx)
{
CAMOpt(m, 'AssetDetails (new window)', 'javascript:window.open(\'http://infpw03403:15000/Lists/Asset%20Repository/DispForm.aspx?ID=' +{ItemId}+'\');' ,'/_layouts/images/LIST.GIF');
return false;
}

</script>
```

If I replace  {ItemId} by 216 or any particular currentItemId, it work.

But my problem have how to get dynamic currentItemId ({ItemId}), which  click "AssetDetails (new window)" then will get crossponding details.
or any other method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{ItemId}` will not work here as it works only in Feature definitions.

Take a look at this article

http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/09.aspx

`currentItemID` should do the trick.

Comment: hey... through currentItemID , can  we get value of element ?